# First sample size is always 10 entries in caret RFE

Tags: r, data-mining

I'm trying to implement my custom function for feature ranking with caret package. The problem is every time the summary function is called for the first time I get only 10 entries. This is not a problem here, but in a bigger dataset where one class would be only a small fraction (say 5%) of all entries it can happen that it would not be selected at all

```
l = lmFuncs
l$summary = function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
  print(dim(data))
  if (is.character(data$obs)) 
    data$obs <- factor(data$obs, levels = lev)
  postResample(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
}

rfe(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*3), ncol=3)), sample(2, 100, replace=T), sizes=1:3, rfeControl=rfeControl(functions=l, number=20))
```

output:

```
[1] 10  2
[1] 32  3
[1] 32  3
[1] 32  3
[1] 40  3
[1] 40  3
[1] 40  3
[1] 37  3
[1] 37  3
[1] 37  3
...
```

R sessionInfo:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] pROC_1.5.4         kernlab_0.9-14     e1071_1.6-1        class_7.3-5        caret_5.15-044     foreach_1.4.0      cluster_1.14.3     reshape_0.8.4      plyr_1.7.1        
[10] lattice_0.20-10    Biobase_2.18.0     BiocGenerics_0.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_2.15.1 grid_2.15.1     iterators_1.0.6 tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: I get more than 10 entries.  Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: About six months ago, my lab mate found what we thought was a bug in rfe / rfeIter.  It seemed to evaluate fit using a number of predictor variables equal to the previous (not current) subset size. I am away from my computer so I can't run it to see if it still seems buggy but my labmate's bug demo code is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pPsKSxCiUdA8cKGijoGT8QRbls4AyY57l2N7pscDROA/edit

Comment: When you say you thought that it was a bug, does that mean you were wrong?

Comment: @Dason , what is different your `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 1):

`rfe`, `train` and `sbf` all do a preliminary check of the summary function before doing any model function (to get the names of the metrics to check with, etc).

One of the first things these functions do is take a random sample (n = 10) of the data set and run the summary function.

So, this has nothing to do with your actual modeling process.

Max

Comment: Ok, what if my proportions of two classes in dataset are say 1/100? My score function is basically AUC. The problem is I can't calculate AUC without any positive entries in the provided sample and most of the time there will be none because of the 1/100 proportions?

Comment: Hi, a follow up question. What would be proper return value in this case? Would a named vector with NA for each calculated metric be fine?